# Python regex: having trouble understanding results

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe that I need to write to disk but pyspark doesn't allow any of these characters `,;{}()\\n\\t=` to be present in the headers while writing as a parquet file.

So I wrote a simple script to detect if this is happening

```
import re
for each_header in all_headers:
  print(re.match(",;{}()\\n\\t= ", each_header))
```

But for each header, `None` was printed. This is wrong because I know my file has spaces in its headers.
So, I decided to check it out by executing the following couple of lines

```
a = re.match(",;{}()\\n\\t= ", 'a s')
print(a)
a = re.search(",;{}()\\n\\t= ", 'a s')
print(a)
```

This too resulted in `None` getting printed.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

PS: I am using python3.7

Comment: You probably need a character class `[,;{}()\\n\\\\t=]`.

Comment: Your regex match those characters all together. Have you tried the token `[` and `]` `([,;{}\(\)\\n\\t=])` ?

Comment: To the above two comments, we _don't_ need to double escape things like `\n` in a character class, just one backslash is sufficient.  And `(){}` do not require any escaping at all.

Comment: `print((a.groups()))` You can see the words that are matching your pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `{}` and also `()` are regex metacharacters, and have a special meaning.  Perhaps the easiest way to write your logic would be to use the pattern:

```
[,;{}()\n\t=]
```

This says to match the *literal* characters which PySpark does not allow to be present in the headers.

```
a = re.match("[,;{}()\n\t=]", 'a s')
print(a)
```

If you wanted to remove these characters, you could try using `re.sub`:

```
header = '...'
header = re.sub(r'[,;{}()\n\t=]+', '', header)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a text contains **any** of the "forbidden"
characters, you have to put them between `[` and `]`.

Another flaw in your regex is that in "normal" strings (not *r-strings*)
any backslash should be **doubled**.

So change your regex to:

```
"[,;{}()\\n\\t= ]"
```

Or use *r-string*:

```
r"[,;{}()\n\t= ]"
```

Note that I included also a **space**, which you missed.

One more remark: `{}` and `()` have special meaning, but **outside** `[...]`.
Between  `[` and `]` they represent themselves, so they need no
quotation with a backslash.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I have edited the question to include the space

Answer (score 1):

As already explained you could use regex for looking for forbidden characters, I want to add that you could do it without using regex following way:

```
forbidden = ",;{}()\n\t="
def has_forbidden(txt):
    for i in forbidden:
        if i in txt:
            return True
    return False
print(has_forbidden("ok name")) # False
print(has_forbidden("wrong=name")) # True
print(has_forbidden("with\nnewline")) # True
```

Note that using this approach you do not have to care about escaping special-regex characters, like for example `*`.